# hibernate foreign key issue : Error executing DDL "alter table..."

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have a pretty simple object structure that is giving me an error I'm not able to resolve. Have done a bunch of searching, and I think this must be a pretty common use case, so not sure what the issue is. I have these three classes:

```
@Entity
public class Widget {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idd;
    private Date date;
    private String type;
    private int ownerId;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Rating rating;


    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Tag> tagList;


}


@Entity
public class Rating {
public enum ChartType  {RADAR, BAR, LINE, STAR};

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int ratingId;
private String name;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ChartType chartType;
private double normalizedValue;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<RatingComponent> componentList = new ArrayList<>();


public Rating() {
    buildNormalizedValue();
}
}


@Entity
public class RatingComponent {


@Id
@GeneratedValue()
private int compId;

private String name;
private double value;
private double maxValue;

}
```

when saving in the DAO I'm getting errors I don't really understand, such as

```
2018-07-23 11:43:07,208 WARN o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl [main] GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : 
Error executing DDL "alter table Rating_RatingComponent drop foreign key FKaudjguwlo1i8tm2jgli5bbnq6" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table Rating_RatingComponent drop foreign key FKaudjguwlo1i8tm2jgli5bbnq6" via JDBC Statement
```

and further down

```
2018-07-23 11:43:07,644 WARN o.h.t.s.i.ExceptionHandlerLoggedImpl [main] GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL "create table RatingComponent (compId integer not null, maxValue double precision not null, name varchar(255), value double precision not null, primary key (compId)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table RatingComponent (compId integer not null, maxValue double precision not null, name varchar(255), value double precision not null, primary key (compId)) engine=InnoDB" via JDBC Statement
```

I have these properties in my config

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

I thought I had gone thru the docs pretty carefully, and think this is a pretty straight forward object design...any ideas as to how to resolve, and where in the docs should I research more carefully to understand the root cause?

thanks!

Comment: clear out the database and try again.

Comment: I dropped the database and re-created, and had the same problem. Also note that I have the 'create' property set, so a new db is created on each run of a unit test

Comment: Works fine for me: `Hibernate: alter table Rating_RatingComponent add constraint FKaudjguwlo1i8tm2jgli5bbnq6 foreign key (componentList_compId) references RatingComponent` Removed the Tag from Widget since you didn't bother to post a Complete, Minimal, Verifiable example

Comment: I see your output shows a table name of Rating_RatingComponent, wheras mine only shows RatingComponent, and that table does not exist in the db....

Comment: Your question is about the Rating_RatingComponent table. That's what your error is. It's a join table between Rating and RatingComponent. If you have an existing database structure you should be using auto value validate.

Answer (score 6):

I had used an SQL reserved word `'order'` as the entity name, due to which I was getting a similar error. Renaming it solved it for me. Look at your entity names, have you used any reserved word in them?

Comment: I've had a similar issue with a class named "Match".

Answer (score 3):

replacing

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
```

by

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8InnoDBDialect</property>
```

will do the trick

Comment: 3 years later, you save my ass bro. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had to drop-create all the tables to make it work. Also check if you are using any reserved words as your table names.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error in a `@OneToMany` relation with the option `orphanRemoval = true`. In fact, from JPA documentation:

> Whether to apply the remove operation to entities that have been
> removed from the relationship and to cascade the remove operation to
> those entities.

So, if you create a table A, populate it, and then you want to create a table B (empty at begining, of course) with a foreign key to table A, then you'll get the "alter table xxx drop foreign key" error.

Removing the property from:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
```

to:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the DB User didnt have the sufficient permission to alter the table using the reference command. Hint Stack trace had the error like

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: REFERENCES command denied to user

Updating the DB User privileges fixed the issue

Also use the update as ddl-auto

jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update