# Spring Boot app Heroku PostgreSQL error : GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL ... via JDBC Statement

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, heroku

I created a small social media app with Spring Boot and in development I used H2 local database and it worked just fine. Now I try to connect it to a Heroku PostgreSQL database and I get the error in the title. Any ideas why?
I suspected a wrong dialect, but everywhere I checked I should use org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect as I do right now. Otherwise probably there're some mishaps with the Entities or the Mapping? Even if yes, I just can't figure what and how to amend them.
I'm quite new to database stuff, so please don't judge me if it's some stupid mistake.

Entity class : User

```
package com.schabby.socialplatform.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;

@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name="seq", initialValue=1, allocationSize=100)
public class User implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY, generator="seq")
    private Long id;
    
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String picture;
    private boolean online;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "User")
    private Collection<Post> posts = new ArrayList<Post>();

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String username, String password, String name, int age, String picture, boolean online) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.picture = picture;
        this.online = online;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Collection<Post> getPosts() {
        return posts;
    }

    public void setPosts(Collection<Post> posts) {
        this.posts = posts;
    }

    public boolean isOnline() {
        return online;
    }

    public void setOnline(boolean online) {
        this.online = online;
    }

    public String getPicture() {
        return picture;
    }

    public void setPicture(String picture) {
        this.picture = picture;
    }
    
    
    
}
```

Entity class: Post

```
package com.schabby.socialplatform.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

@Entity
public class Post implements Serializable {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    
    private String text;
    
    @Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date date;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="User_id")
    private User User;
    
    
    public Post() {
    }

    public Post(String text, Date date, User user) {
        this.text = text;
        this.date = date;
        this.User = user;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(Date date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return User;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.User = user;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.schabby</groupId>
    <artifactId>socialplatform</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>socialplatform</name>
    <description>Social Media Platform</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.6</version>
      <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties :

```
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=10MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=10MB

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54-217-206-236.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:5432/d5rk5sir0732uc?sslmode=require
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Thank you for every suggestions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found an answer here on Stackoverflow!

The problem was that some names, like my table's name: 'user' is reserved for PostgreSQL. So, changing the name of it solved my issue.

Here's the original answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56206827/13304501

Comment: Well, I spent few hours dealing with this issue. Thank you so much for posting this. This totally solved my problem. If you most use user as a table name you can mark your entity with: @Table(name="\"user\"") and that will do the trick.

Comment: Holy jesus, another victim here. god

Answer (score 2):

I had also the same error, and I had User entity class gave annotation `@Table`, but I saw that I should declare the name of table and I made it the same with my class name as `@Table(name ="user")` but user is used as reserved keyword in PostgreSQL, I changed it into `@Table(name ="users")`. Then it worked for me. The solution found from here, [Executing DDL Commands in Spring-Boot](https://java.tutorialink.com/how-to-resolve-error-executing-ddl-commands-in-spring-boot/)
I hope this helps you too.