# Problem with one-to-many in Spring Boot project

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, jpa

i have these two class below: product and category, as you can see there is a bidirectional one-to-many relationship. evertithing works but the application throws me the error i posted below and i don't know why.

```
@Entity(name = "product")
@Table(name = "product",
        uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "unique_eancode_constraint", columnNames = "ean_code")
)

@Getter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Setter
public class ProductModel {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name="product_sequence",
            sequenceName = "product_sequence",
            initialValue = 0,
            allocationSize = 1
    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "product_sequence"
    )
    private Long id;
    @Column(
            name = "ean_code",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false,
            columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(13)"
    )
    private String eanCode;
    @Column(
            name = "product_name",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false,
            columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(100)"

    )
    private String name;
    @Column(
            name = "price",
            nullable = false

    )
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Column(
            name = "quantity",
            nullable = false

    )
    private Integer quantity;
    @Column(
            name = "weight",
            nullable = false,
            updatable = false,
            scale = 3
    )
    private Double weight;
    @Column(
            name = "description",
            columnDefinition = "TEXT"
    )
    private String description;
    @ManyToOne
    private CategoryModel category;


    public ProductModel(String eanCode,
                        String name,
                        BigDecimal price,
                        Integer quantity,
                        Double weight,
                        String description,
                        CategoryModel categoryModel) {
        this.eanCode = eanCode;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.description = description;
        this.category = categoryModel;
    }



        public ProductModel(String eanCode, String name, BigDecimal price, Integer quantity, Double weight, String description) {
            this.eanCode = eanCode;
            this.name = name;
            this.price = price;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.weight = weight;
            this.description = description;
        }
    
    
        public ProductModel(ProductDTO productDTO) {
            this.eanCode = productDTO.getEancode();
            this.name = productDTO.getName();
            this.price = productDTO.getPrice();
            this.quantity = productDTO.getQuantity();
            this.weight = productDTO.getWeight();
            this.description = productDTO.getDescription();
        }
```

}

```
  @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @ToString
    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Entity(name = "category")
    @Table(name = "category",
            uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "unique_name_constraint", columnNames = "category_name")
    )
    public class CategoryModel {
        @Id
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "category_sequence",
                sequenceName = "category_sequence",
                initialValue = 0,
                allocationSize = 1
        )
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
                generator = "category_sequence"
        )
        private Long id;
        @Column(name = "category_name",
                nullable = false
        )
        private String name;
        @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
               mappedBy = "category",
                orphanRemoval = true
        )
        private Set<ProductModel> products;
    
        public CategoryModel(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    
        public void addProduct(ProductModel productModel){
            if(this.products == null) products = new HashSet<>();
            this.products.add(productModel);
            productModel.setCategory(this);
        }
    /*
        public void removeProduct(ProductModel productModel){
            this.products.remove(productModel);
            productModel.setCategory(null);
        }
    */
    }
```

this is the error. there are no other tables in the db (i'm using mySQL) which the same names.

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "alter table product drop foreign key FK1mtsbur82frn64de7balymq9s" via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504230/how-to-fix-error-executing-ddl-alter-table-events-drop-foreign-key-fkg0mkvgsqn

Comment: the problem was "create-drop"...thanks!

Comment: Please either add this as the answer or delete your question. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PeterMmmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114226/petermmm) wrote the answer to this problem: [How to fix "Error executing DDL "alter table events drop foreign key FKg0mkvgsqn8584qoql6a2rxheq" via JDBC Statement"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54504230/how-to-fix-error-executing-ddl-alter-table-events-drop-foreign-key-fkg0mkvgsqn)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

1. One sugestions is your config into "ProductModel "

   ```
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_category") // @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private CategoryModel category;
   ```
2. Then do maping into "CategoryModel" to use  foreign key column instead of an association table to map the relationship.

   ```
   @JoinColumn(name = "fk_category")        
   private Set<ProductModel> products;
   ```
3. But if you intend to use "CategoryModel" for more than one products is necessary reviewer your maping

Reference: https://thorben-janssen.com/best-practices-many-one-one-many-associations-mappings/

Comment: i don't understand what  do you mean with "But if you intend to use "CategoryModel" for more than one products is necessary reviewer your maping". I'm using "CategoryModel" for map one category with several products that has the same category. if you mean use more Set of ProductModel in the same CategoryModel ok, i know that i have to review the class